# Moving to version 2016 from 2008 and Breaking Change Alert from Upgrade Advisor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, upgrade

DBMS: SQL Server

Upgrading from version 2008 to 2016.

I have this part of the code that is being flagged by the Upgrade adviser as Breaking Change.

> Error:  uses a constant expression which are not allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause in database compatibility level 90 or later

What am I missing here. To my understanding, I should not use constants here but like variables. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    DECLARE ForeignColumn1 CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
    SELECT 
      a.COLUMN_NAME
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.COLUMN_NAME) AS RowNumber
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE a
    WHERE 1=1
    AND a.CONSTRAINT_NAME = @Constraint
    AND a.TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
    AND a.COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE
    CASE 
        WHEN @SkipSite > 0 THEN 
             @CurrSite
        ELSE
             ''
        END
    ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Comment: This looks like a bogus warning to me with the deprecated Upgrade Advisor. If you only need static analysis, consider using the [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595
) instead.

Comment: yes you are correct. The original code contained ORDER by 'RowNumber' and (ORDER BY a.COLUMN_NAME) AS 'RowNumber'. I ended up replacing 'RowNumber' with [RowNumber] and the analysis didn't throw any alerts.  ---- Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Going from 2008 to 2016 is jumping too far.

I suggest you to go move to 2012 first and then to 2016.

1. First of all download [Microsoft Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) and try to spot incompatibilities.
2. Then download [Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7826) and scan for all sort of incompatibilities following a [guide](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-microsoft-assessment-and-planning-map-toolkit-for-sql-server/).
3. Spot the incompatible queries using the [Query Tuning Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/upgrade-dbcompat-using-qta?view=sql-server-ver15)

Now that you are on 2012 repeat the steps 1, 2 and 3 and move to 2016.